# WebGrid will not automatically refresh when one of the fields gets an asynchronous update

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to asynchronously update a database table field using jQuery. I am successfully doing it but I have to hit F5 to refresh the screen to see the change. I am trying to get where the webgrid that contains the database table fields will automatically update its content when one of its field changes through the asynchronous update.

Here is the jQuery part which works:

```
var printermapping =
{
    "MTPrinterID": MTPrinterID,
    "NTPrinterID": NTPrinterID,
    "Active": "Y"
};
$.ajax({
     url: '/Home/UpdatePrinterMapping/',
     data: JSON.stringify(printermapping),
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 });
```

So I am asynchronously calling UpdatePrinterMapping Action in my Home Controller. The Action looks like:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePrinterMapping(PrinterMapping printermapping)
{
    // Update printermapping to your db
    var printer = db.PrinterMapping.Find(printermapping.MTPrinterID);

    if (printer == null)
    {
            // this cannot happen according to current structure
    }
    else
    {
       try
       {
           db.Entry(printer).Member("Active").CurrentValue = printermapping.Active;
           db.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           throw new Exception("General Exception occurred while saving to database");
       }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

My Index Action looks like:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    PrinterViewModel printerModel = new PrinterViewModel();
    printerModel.Printers = from mapping in db.PrinterMapping select mapping;

    return View(printerModel);
}
```

My PrinterViewModel ViewModel looks like:

```
public class PrinterViewModel
{
    public PrinterMapping PrinterMapping;
    public Exceptions Exceptions;
    public IEnumerable<PrinterMapping> Printers;

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PrinterOptions
    {
        get { return new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Y", "N" }); }
    }
}
```

where PrinterMapping class is the EF generated data class:

```
public partial class PrinterMapping
{
    public string MTPrinterID { get; set; }
    public string NTPrinterID { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
}
```

This is probably more info than needed but at least you have it all. Many thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great resource that explains exactly what I need to do.

[Mikesdotnetting](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/155/WebMatrix-And-jQuery-Forms)